# Understanding Dart Default Constructors

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

I am coming from a Java background and trying to understand Dart. The Dart documentation states that:

> If you don’t declare a constructor, a default constructor is provided for you.

Consider the following then:

```
//Dart code; dart_app.dart
class Person{

   int age;
   String name;

   Person({@required this.name, this.age});

   Person.fromPerson(Person person){
     age = person.age;
     name = person.name;
   }
}
```

The person class has two constructors, so according to the docs, a default constructor will not be provided. Now I declare a subclass like so:

```
//Dart code; dart_app.dart
class Student extends Person{

  int rank;

  Student(this.rank);
}
```

I expect that instantiating `Student`, as defined, requires a call to the superclass (i.e. `Person`) no-arg constructor. But since a no-arg constructor was not explicitly defined and since Dart (according to the docs) will not provide a default no-arg constructor (since other constructors have been explicitly defined) I expect a compile error. I get none. What am I missing?

The equivalent Java code below fails to compile as expected:

```
//Java code; File Person.java
package com.company;

public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
//Java code; File Student.java
package com.company;

public class Student extends Person {
    int rank;
}
```

Student.java compile fails as expected: **There is no default constructor available in 'com.company.Person'**.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All parameters of constructor **Person** are optional, which allows you to create instance of Student. In that case super constructor **Person** will be implicitly called with no parameters, thus allowing you to instantiate Student.

Please note that **@required** annotation is not language level, so does not make **name** strictly required.